# In English, what rules govern the optimal order of nouns in a list?

Tags: phonology, word-order, sentences

For example, is noun word-order governed by a universal ranking of semantic fields, as with adjectives, or do other considerations in general English word choice and order (well-formedness of resulting prosodic phrases, phonetic alliteration or assonance, etc.) have some influence as well?

In an extreme case, I can image that a certain context-dependent logical ordering does necessarily hold. When listing arguments to be made at the opening of a paper, for example, a certain chronological or logical flow is to-be expected.

However, when  all of the items to be listed are semantically similar, I can't help but feel that, for example,

"I bought apples, bananas and berries."

sounds more natural than

"I bought berries, bananas and apples."

Part of me has a suspicion that "bought apples" rolls off the tongue better due to the potential elision of the t, but more formal arguments, research and papers would be appreciated. This argument, though, seems less unique to the listing of nouns and relevant to English word choice/ order more generally.

Comment: It can also be due to what a person _thinks_ or which object is more _primed_ to him when it comes to buying stuff (as in your example).

Comment: I think Ross wrote on this in the 70's, but at this point I don't remember what paper.